# conditional expectation of gamma distribution with $\alpha = 1$

Tags: statistics, conditional-expectation, exponential-distribution, gamma-distribution

$X_i$ are exponential($\lambda$) distribution and identically independent distribution.

$Y = \sum_{i=1}^nX_i$

$X_i$ is an unbiased estimator of $\lambda$.

$Y$ is a sufficient estimator of $\lambda$.

solve $E[X_1|Y]$

---

I know that $Y$ is Gamma distribution // $gamma(1,1/\lambda)$

but i can't solve this problem.

how to solve this problem?

Comment: $Y$ is a sufficient statistic of $\lambda$ rather than an estimator.  Its shape parameter is $n$ rather than the $1$ you suggest

Comment: thanks! i wrote it wrong!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Consider $$\mathbb E\left[X_1 \mid Y\right] = E\left[X_j \mid Y\right] = \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb E\left[X_i \mid Y\right]=  \frac1n\mathbb E\left[\sum_{i=1}^nX_i \;\Bigg| \; Y\right]$$

Comment: thanks a lot!
but i don't know that i understand well.
E[\X_1\+\X_2\+...+\X_n\|Y]=E[\X_1\|Y]+E[\X_2\|Y]+...E[\X_n\|Y]  required that X and Y are independent?

Comment: @JeonSeokJun You did not quite finish that comment, but I would guess you intended $\mathbb E[Y \mid Y]$.  If you did, then that would be equal to  $Y$

Comment: @JeonSeokJun Now you have finished the comment - independence is not required and indeed is not present here.  Your expression is true because of [linearity of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity)